# CSS animations: after completing first animation set display block at start of second animation WITHOUT JAVASCRIPT

Tags: html, css, animation

is it possible to set css value from display: none to display: block at the start of second animation **without JAVASCRIPT**? Thanks. This is where I am so far: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyMmNm

HTML:

```
<main>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
h1{
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  animation-name: h1FadeIn;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

p{
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  animation-name: pFadeIn;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}


@keyframes h1FadeIn{
  from{ opacity: 0;margin-bottom: 0em; }
  to{ opacity: 1;margin-bottom: 3em; }
}

@keyframes pFadeIn{
  from{ opacity: 0;margin-left: 3em;display: block; }
  to{opacity: 1;margin-left: 0em;display: block; }
}
```

Comment: You can't animate the `display` property.

Comment: first you are calling the the h1 animation for the p also

Comment: @TemaniAfif edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.

STYLE CSS:

```
<style>
h1{
  animation-name: h1FadeIn;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

p{
  opacity:0;
  animation-name: pFadeIn;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes h1FadeIn{
  from{ opacity: 0;margin-left: 3em; }
  to{ opacity: 1;margin-left: 0em; }
}

@keyframes pFadeIn{
  from{ opacity: 0;margin-left: 3em; }
  to{ opacity: 1;margin-left: 0em; }
}
</style>
```

BODY HTML:

```
<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    </main>
</body>
```